# aplay only works as root on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi

This is a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, running pretty vanilla Raspbian 10. `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` doesn't work as user `pi`, member of group `audio`, but does work with `sudo` as root. I'd like playback to happen through the 3.5mm headphone jack.

Two important clues which make me think the solution is obvious but I'm not clued in on Linux audio to figure it out:

1. This works fine if I boot the Pi connected to a display and try playing from the GUI. It fails when I run it headless and try to play over `ssh`.
2. The different outputs of `amixer` vs `sudo amixer`, quoted below.

```
$ amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Mono: Capture 3 [0%] [on]
$ sudo amixer
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback -10239 - 400
  Mono: Playback 400 [100%] [4.00dB] [on]
$
```

What am I missing? I'm looking for a fix that will change the default behaviour for all programs, not just `amixer`. Thanks!

Comment: I've discovered from another question that removing pulseaudio (`apt-get remove pulseaudio`) magically fixes things (sound works for user `pi` and `root`) but no idea why. It seems that if pulseaudio is present, aplay goes to it as `pi` and bypasses it as `root`, but why is that, or why doesn't pulseaudio work, or what prices will I pay in the future for removing pulseaudio without knowing why I'm doing it... no idea.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across some Forums that removing the "~/.asoundrc" helped solving the issue
you can do the same by

```
sudo rm ~/.asoundrc
```

and also check if the user is added to audio group if not you can do that by

```
sudo adduser "username" audio
```

Or the simple solution could be using omxplayer or mpv player

```
omxplayer test.wav
```

**Note**: You need to install omxplayer manually if you are on a lite version of raspbian OS you can install it with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install omxplayer
```

Comment: Removing .asoundrc worked. I found this problem with lite install of raspbian.